# reCAPTCHA position cannot be changed (from bottom right)

Tags: css, recaptcha

I have just added a reCAPTCHA v3 to a contact form, however I am unable to change the position from the bottom right of the page.

**Position on No Hover**
[image]

**Position on Hover**
[image]

After following this [tutorial](https://themehunt.com/blog/28-web-tips-and-tricks/bootstrap-tips-and-tricks/168-how-to-add-recaptcha-to-bootstrap-contact-form) and looking for solutions, all reCAPTCHA examples embed the div in a bootstrap contact form. As I am not using bootstrap, I would like to simply position the element using css.

Things I've tried:

- Remove all elements in the page - the position does not change
- Remove all elements in the contact div - the position does not change
- Push changes to actual website - the local host error goes away, but the position doesn't change
- Triple check the code: `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="KEY" id="recaptcha" name="recaptcha" style="left=0px;position=absolute"></div>`

Comment: Where do you want to position it? That tutorial is for reCAPTCHA **v2** and your question is about v3

Comment: I would like to position it in the contact form div below the email text field.

Comment: I'm not completely sure that you understand the principle of reCAPTCHA v3: It works without any user interaction (No more "I'm not a robot" checkbox), and therefore it shouldn't be a part of the form

Comment: Check [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbvxFW4UJdU) for more details on how it works

Comment: Ah! So if it's simply on the page with ```visibility=none``` it will be functioning?

Comment: Yep, exactly :)

Comment: Amazing thank you! Great video also. If you post your answer I'll accept whenever.

Comment: I have to go so you can self-answer or just delete this post and implement it as you wish - Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer thanks to @AlonEitan. The reCAPTCHA v3 has no UI interface. So instead of embedding it in the contact form (as with v2), you simply hide the banner:

```
<div class="grecaptcha-recaptcha" data-sitekey="KEY" id="recaptcha" name="recaptcha" style="opacity=0;"></div>
```

[Source](https://brizzo.net/tips/hide-recaptcha-v3-badge/)